# Customized PasswordResetSerializer and now it's throwing error 500

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

I am contributing to an open-source org where they are using `django-rest-auth` for authentication purposes. I have to simply override the email template for a password reset. So I used imported `PasswordResetSerializer` and then customized it. It worked in the first place but when I restarted the whole environment it stopped working and just showed this in terminal

```
django_1     | [pid: 65|app: 0|req: 1/1] 172.19.0.1 () {42 vars in 696 bytes} [Thu Jan  7 22:06:59 2021] OPTIONS /api/auth/password/reset/ => generated 0 bytes in 4 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 7 headers in 365 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
django_1     | [pid: 67|app: 0|req: 1/2] 172.19.0.1 () {42 vars in 696 bytes} [Thu Jan  7 22:06:59 2021] POST /api/auth/password/reset/ => generated 22264 bytes in 796 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 5 headers in 177 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

It's showing me error 500.
I tried to use debugger but here the all environment is setup using docker and I couldn't figure out what's going wrong.

Here are the files

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for evalai project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import datetime
import os
import sys

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
APPS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "apps")

sys.path.append(APPS_DIR)

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("SECRET_KEY", "random_secret_key")

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEST = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

EVALAI_API_SERVER = os.environ.get("EVALAI_API_SERVER", "http://localhost:8000")

# Application definition

DEFAULT_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "django.contrib.sites",
]

OUR_APPS = [
    "accounts",
    "analytics",
    "base",
    "challenges",
    "hosts",
    "jobs",
    "participants",
    "web",
]

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    "allauth",
    "allauth.account",
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    "corsheaders",
    "django_ses",
    "import_export",
    "rest_auth",
    "rest_auth.registration",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_expiring_authtoken",
    "drf_yasg",
    "django_filters",
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DEFAULT_APPS + OUR_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "evalai.urls"


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ]
        },
    }
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "evalai.wsgi.application"


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator"  # noqa
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator"  # noqa
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator"  # noqa
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator"  # noqa
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"

SITE_ID = 1

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": (
        "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination"
    ),
    "PAGE_SIZE": 100,
    "TEAM_PAGE_SIZE": 10,
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly"
    ],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_expiring_authtoken.authentication.ExpiringTokenAuthentication"
    ],
    "TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT": "json",
    "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle",
        "rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES": {
        "anon": "100/minute",
        "user": "100/minute",
        "resend_email": "3/hour",
    },
    "DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES": ("rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer",),
}

# ALLAUTH SETTINGS
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED = True
ACCOUNT_CONFIRM_EMAIL_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = (
    "/api/auth/email-confirmed/"
)
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL = (
    "/api/auth/email-confirmed/"
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get("AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME")
AWS_ACCOUNT_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCOUNT_ID", "aws_account_id")
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", "aws_access_key_id")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get(
    "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", "aws_secret_access_key"
)
AWS_REGION = os.environ.get("AWS_DEFAULT_REGION", "us-east-1")

# Broker url for celery
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "sqs://%s:%s@" % (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

# CORS Settings
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

# REST Framework Expiring Tokens Configuration
EXPIRING_TOKEN_LIFESPAN = datetime.timedelta(days=365)

# Logging
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "root": {"level": "INFO", "handlers": ["console"]},
    "filters": {
        "require_debug_false": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse"},
        "require_debug_true": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue"},
    },
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
        "verbose": {
            "format": "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s %(module)s %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "level": "INFO",
            "filters": ["require_debug_true"],
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "simple",
        },
        "logfile": {
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "filename": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "django.log"),
            "maxBytes": 50000,
            "backupCount": 10,
            "formatter": "verbose",
        },
        "mail_admins": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
            "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {"handlers": ["console"], "propagate": False},
        "django.request": {
            "handlers": ["mail_admins"],
            "level": "ERROR",
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "django.security": {
            "handlers": ["mail_admins"],
            "level": "ERROR",
            "propagate": False,
        },
        "django.db.backends": {
            "handlers": ["mail_admins"],
            "level": "ERROR",
            "propagate": False,
        },
    },
}

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache"
    }
}

# The maximum size in bytes for request body
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#data-upload-max-memory-size
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 4294967296  # 4 GB
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 4294967296  # 4 GB

# To make usermame field read-only, customized serializer is defined.
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    "USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.ProfileSerializer",
    "PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER": "accounts.serializers.CustomPasswordResetSerializer"
}

# For inviting users to participant and host teams.
ADMIN_EMAIL = "admin@cloudcv.org"
CLOUDCV_TEAM_EMAIL = "EvalAI Team <team@cloudcv.org>"

# Expiry time of a presigned url for uploading files to AWS, in seconds.
PRESIGNED_URL_EXPIRY_TIME = 3600

# Slack web hook url
SLACK_WEB_HOOK_URL = os.environ.get(
    "SLACK_WEB_HOOK_URL", "http://testslackwebhook.com/webhook"
)

SWAGGER_SETTINGS = {
    "DEFAULT_INFO": "evalai.urls.swagger_api_info",
    "SECURITY_DEFINITIONS": {
        "Token Authentication": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "Authorization",
            "in": "header",
        }
    },
}

REDOC_SETTINGS = {"SPEC_URL": ("docs.yaml", {"format": ".yaml"})}

DJANGO_SERVER = os.environ.get("DJANGO_SERVER")
DJANGO_SERVER_PORT = os.environ.get("DJANGO_SERVER_PORT")

HOSTNAME = os.environ.get("HOSTNAME")

SENDGRID_SETTINGS = {
    "TEMPLATES": {
        "CHALLENGE_INVITATION": "d-60825bcf014f4958bdb1b9173471d420",
        "CHALLENGE_APPROVAL_EMAIL": "d-45e0adc0597b4b60bd7c384aa903c488",
        "WORKER_RESTART_EMAIL": "d-3d9a474a5e2b4ac4ad5a45ba9c0b84bd",
        "CLUSTER_CREATION_TEMPLATE": "d-6de90fd760df4a41bb9bff1872eaab82",
        "WORKER_START_EMAIL": "d-debd127cab2345e789538131501ff416",
    }
}

# EKS configs for Rl-worker
EKS_CLUSTER_ROLE_ARN = os.environ.get("EKS_CLUSTER_ROLE_ARN")

EKS_NODEGROUP_ROLE_ARN = os.environ.get("EKS_NODEGROUP_ROLE_ARN")

ENVIRONMENT = os.environ.get("ENVIRONMENT", "dev")
```

serializers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer


class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Make username as a read_only field.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = (
            "pk",
            "email",
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "password",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("email", "username")


class ProfileSerializer(UserDetailsSerializer):
    """
    Serializer to update the user profile.
    """

    affiliation = serializers.CharField(source="profile.affiliation")
    github_url = serializers.URLField(
        source="profile.github_url", allow_blank=True
    )
    google_scholar_url = serializers.URLField(
        source="profile.google_scholar_url", allow_blank=True
    )
    linkedin_url = serializers.URLField(
        source="profile.linkedin_url", allow_blank=True
    )

    class Meta(UserDetailsSerializer.Meta):
        fields = (
            "pk",
            "email",
            "username",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "affiliation",
            "github_url",
            "google_scholar_url",
            "linkedin_url",
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        profile_data = validated_data.pop("profile", {})
        affiliation = profile_data.get("affiliation")
        github_url = profile_data.get("github_url")
        google_scholar_url = profile_data.get("google_scholar_url")
        linkedin_url = profile_data.get("linkedin_url")

        instance = super(ProfileSerializer, self).update(
            instance, validated_data
        )

        profile = instance.profile
        if profile_data and affiliation:
            profile.affiliation = affiliation
            profile.github_url = github_url
            profile.google_scholar_url = google_scholar_url
            profile.linkedin_url = linkedin_url
            profile.save()
        return instance


class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
    def get_email_options(self):
        super().get_email_options()
        return {
            'subject_template_name': 'account/email/password_reset_key_subject.txt',
            'email_template_name': 'account/password_reset_email.html',
            'html_email_template_name': 'account/password_reset_email.html',
            }
```

I've been stuck to this issue for about 1 week and I'm losing my confidence.

open source project is [here](https://github.com/Cloud-CV/EvalAI), incase you want to check.

**UPDATE** - Now I'm getting another problem in which my email looks like this, I'm not getting the variable passed here.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II5ej.png)

And it should look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj2gN.png)

password_reset_email.html

```
{% load i18n %}{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}Hello from {{ site_name }}!

You're receiving this e-mail because you or someone else has requested a password for your user account at {{ site_domain }}.
It can be safely ignored if you did not request a password reset. Click the link below to reset your password.{% endblocktrans %}

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}

{% if username %}{% blocktrans %}In case you forgot, your username is {{ username }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% endif %}{% blocktrans with site_name=current_site.name site_domain=current_site.domain %}Thank you for using {{ site_name }}!
{{ site_domain }}{% endblocktrans %}
```

**UPDATE - I solved this issue by changing the extension from html to txt. It's strange I know but worked for me.**

Comment: look into log and post error traceback

Comment: @iklinac I was able to solve this question but now I'm getting another error, I'm updating this error itself, please take some time to provide answer.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this answer by simply putting this `logging` code to `settings.py` file.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'NOTSET',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': 'NOTSET',
        },
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
            'level': 'ERROR'
        }
    }
}
```

The org in which I was contributing they were using docker file to setup the environment and they have edited the logging file according to them.
By adding that code to the settings file I was able to receive the error logs.